# python compare string in list with item starting with \r\n

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, compare

Ok so let's say i have a list.

```
l = ['a', '\r\nb']
```

And a known item to search for.

```
search = 'b'
```

If i type

```
search in l
```

It returns `False`. But if i type.

```
for item in l:
    search in item
```

I will receive

```
False
True
```

The latter one makes sense to me since `'b'`is in `'\r\nb'`. But why oh why isn't `'b'` in `['a', '\r\nb']`

Comment: searched value is not in the list comparing by value, that's normal

Comment: `in` will only search for an exact match in the list.

Comment: Do you actually care about `\r\n`? Why not `.strip` everything in the list, so you're starting from a more sensible place? Then `'b' in ['a', 'b']` would be true. It's not at all clear why you're surprised by this behaviour - what would you expect e.g. `l.index('b')` to be? Do you think it should do a partial match on every `item` all of the time? This would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: So there is a difference when using `in` with a list compared to a singe string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah. sure i could iterate the list and strip each item. But that is not what i want to do. I was asking of the behavior of the keyword `in`.

Comment: But you've demonstrated **with your own example** what the behaviour of `in` is, so it's not clear what you'd still like to know. `'b'` isn't `in ['a', '\r\nb']` because neither element in that list `is` or `==` that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first case (`search in l`) it will try to find exact match for any element of the `list` with your `search` term .

And when you try to recursively go through each of the element and match it's finding in that element which it succseed to find.

Comment: Ah ok i get it. `in`only looks in it own subset. In my mind, the comparison should have been made in the same way in both examples. I understand now why that is not so. First off i thought i hade to do something with \r\n. But it obviously does not. That's just silly.

Answer (score 1):

Because your list items are 'a' and '\r\nb', when you do search in list, it compares each item == 'b', and its FALSE.

'b' is a substring of the second item in the list. 'b' in '\r\nb' is TRUE (your second test), cause it search the substring 'b' in '\r\nb'

Comment: Thank you. Pedagogical explanation.